# Line trimed to .. in gfsh command

Tags: grep, gemfire, geode, gfsh

I am running the below command in Unix box, it is gfsh command:

```
$GEMFIRE_HOME/bin/gfsh -e "connect --locator=$HOST[22710]" -e "list members" | grep "coordinator"
```

but, the catch is, if the returned members contain more than 100 characters then the output is `..` for them , like below:

```
locator:103268:locator)<ec><v87><coordinato..
```

so the `grep` is failing. We know that we can change `grep` pattern, but we want to grep particular coordinator only. 
Why does the output line get trimmed to `..`?

I searched the docs, found below.

https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/91/geode/tools_modules/gfsh/configuring_gfsh.html

> gfsh commands such as `query` produce output with wide columns that may
>   become misaligned and require manual reformatting to view the output.
>   If the output cannot fit in the available width of the terminal, gfsh
>   automatically trims the columns widths to fit. You can disable this
>   behavior by setting the gfsh environment variable `GFSH.TRIMSCRWIDTH` to
>   `false`.

Any suggestions?

I tried to get the only second pattern by `awk '|'`, but still, the coordinator was a coordinator.
Tried `cut` also, didn't work.

```
$GEMFIRE_HOME/bin/gfsh -e "connect --locator=$HOST[22710]" -e "list members" | awk -F'|' '{print $2}'

103268:locator)<ec><v87><coordinato..
```

```
$GEMFIRE_HOME/bin/gfsh -e "connect --locator=$HOST[22710]" -e "list members" | awk -F'|' '{print $2}'
```

should be able to grep "coordinator" the output of gfsh and the output should not have `..` in the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the following to your gfsh command, you should see the full output:

```
-e "set variable --name=APP_RESULT_VIEWER --value=x"
```

This is a workaround - the value `x` is arbitrary and this just avoids the default behavior you're seeing.